# Including in my resume work from a previous country so it will positively affect me finding a job

Tags: software-industry, job-search, pakistan

I just moved from Pakistan to USA. I have done BsCS(hons.) in Pakistan. I worked a job in software industry for 1 and a half years.

I have been doing regular freelance projects in PHP and Python for 2 years.

Will my nationality affect my applying for a job in the US? How should I mention in my resume about the companies/employers I have worked in Pakistan?

Comment: You are currently living in the United States and have a US address?

Comment: Having lived most of your life in Pakistan may negatively affect your ability to get a security clearance in the US, but listing your development experience, regardless of which country it was performed in, should only affect your job search positively.

Answer (score 4):

Your nationality shouldn't matter, there are lots of great developers in the US from India and Pakistan and the regions nearby. Experience coding python is experience coding python, it's the just as useful anywhere in the world.

Just lay your resume out how you normally would, ex. (obviously you want this relevant to your experience, this is just an example - look up 'Developer' or 'Software Engineer' resumes)

```
**Skills**
     Python (2 years), PHP (2 years), IDE (5 years)

**Experience**
Some Company Name, Lead Developer: July 2, 2014 - July 4, 2015
     - Created backend servers using Python...
     - Used some technology to do something...

Some Company Name, Developer: July 2, 2013 - July 4, 2014
     - Created backend servers using Python...
     - Used some technology to do something...

**Education**
Some Schools Name: BSCS, Graduate 2010
     - Something worth mentioning (validvictorian, top of class, scholarships, etc...)
```

also you can contact recruiters, there are tons of them around and they get paid just to find you a job (and not out of your salary) they will help you setup a resume etc...

Comment: I work with some terrific Indian developers.  Their nationality makes no difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

As a recruiter who recruits developers I can safely say people in this field are used to seeing resumes of people who have worked overseas and especially from Pakistan and India. Definitely included relevant experience from Pakistan.

Now that said, the first question that will pop into the mind of any recruiter or hiring manager when they see your resume is "Do they need a visa?" As you know, getting an H1-B visa can be very difficult depending on the time of year. It's usually not the cost of the visa that puts off many companies so much as the uncertainty of being able to even obtain one should they be doled out via lottery as has been the case in recent years. There's also the issue of a delayed start date. Putting down that you have currently hold a H1-B visa will likely help your odds as transferring a visa is a fairly simple process.

Of course if the hiring manager is from India you could encounter some bias...

Comment: Definitely make your visa status clear in your application; don't make an employer have to ask you what your status is.

Comment: I am immigrant from Pak to USA ... so no issue on visa ...